# Qt: How to parse number in a json

Tags: c++, json, qt, parsing, qt5

This is how my json looks like. As you can see, the key `ID` is a number.

```
{
   "id" : 1223324342,
   "name" : "test",
   "files"...
}
```

How can I parse the number and put it in a variable which has a datatype of long? Currently, this is what I have, but this stores 0 instead of the actual value.

```
QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonData);
QJsonObject object = document.object();
product->product_id = object.value(QString("id")).toString().toLong();
```

Comment: I've not used QJsonDocument, but any halfway decent JSON kit should be returning a QVariant or some such as the value of "id".

Comment: Note that this was discussed on the Qt developer's mailing list recently, as other people wanted to read integers in JSON documents with more than 32 bits. Let's see if I can find it...

Comment: Nope, can't find it, sorry. But if I remember correctly, they discussed whether or not a `.toLongLong` (supplementing `.toInt`) makes sense, however I can't remember the argument they had *against* it when they decided *not* to implement it.

Comment: The best way would be to pass your ID parameter as HEX encoded string. This way you would convert it by simple assignment and bit rotation instructions. Otherwise, by converting decimal -> binary you do a lot of division instructions, which increases your time and lowers the performance of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try this instead:

```
product->product_id = object.value(QString("id")).toVariant().toLongLong();
```

[QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvariant.html) unfortunately cannot convert `toLong()` as it can be seen from its documentation.

Comment: `Qt` strictly follows `JSON` standards, and unfortunately even if you convert value to `QVariant`, still 64 Bit integer is not supported to begin with (and `Qt` truncates the value to double).

Answer (score 2):

First, `QJsonObject::value` returns a `QJsonValue`, not a `QVariant`. In contrast to `QVariant`, `QJsonValue` doesn't convert the value when you use a `toSomeType()` function but returns a default value when you request a type different then the one being held by the `QJsonValue`.

Secondly, JSON doesn't support long integers (64 bit). In fact, it only supports integers as "a special case" of doubles. In the JavaScript world, integral and floating point numbers are basically the same (interpreters might *optimize* for integers) and are simply called "numbers".

Qt decided to support 32 bit integers as a special case of numbers. They can be accessed when the value holds a double which is a whole number (according to [the documentation of `QJsonValue::toInt()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#toInt)). Technically, a double can hold whole numbers with up to 54 bits.

So you have two options:

1. get the 32 bit integer value using `toInt()`
2. get the double value using `toDouble()` and cast to `long long` (that's what's happening behind the scenes when you do `toVariant().toLongLong()`)

Comment: "Secondly, JSON doesn't support long integers (64 bit). In fact, it only supports integers as "a special case" of doubles." This limitation is true of javascript, and most uses of JSON will want to interoperate with javascript. However the JSON specs state that the limits and precision of numbers is implementation dependent. It is perfectly legal for implementations to support numbers larger than IEEE double, and several do. QJson is not one of them.